# chef apt_repository fetching fails

Tags: ubuntu, chef, dotdeb

I am trying to fetch a specific repository to install a php version but I keep getting  404 NOT FOUND.

chef recipe code:

```
apt_repository "dotdeb-php54" do
  uri "http://archives.dotdeb.org"
  distribution "squeeze"
  components ["php5/5.4.8"]
  key "http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg"
end
```

Trying to fetch : http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/squeeze/php5/5.4.8

But get the following error :

```
Err http://archives.dotdeb.org squeeze/php5/5.4.8 amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Err http://archives.dotdeb.org squeeze/php5/5.4.8 i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archives.dotdeb.org squeeze/php5/5.4.8 Translation-en
STDERR: W: Failed to fetch http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/squeeze/php5/5.4.8/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

but the following works:

```
apt_repository "dotdeb-php54" do
  uri "http://packages.dotdeb.org"
  distribution "squeeze-php54"
  components ["all"]
  key "http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with Chef. Check the URL you are using and try to run the command `apt-get` manually and then update your recipe. The 404 means the file was not found and this error code is returned by the dotdeb webservers.

I tried opening the URL in my browser and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sameer but this works: http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/squeeze/php5/5.4.8/binary-amd64/ I also updated my question.